# Joe Biden's Student Debt Plan and Public Service

Tags: presidential-election, military, debt

Joe Biden says he will cancel up to $10,000 dollars of student debt for those who are in public service. Most media outlets are defining public service as "schools, gov't jobs, and non-profits." Would the military not also be included in this list? The military is a public service, correct?

Comment: The GI Bill already gives people serving in the military more money for college than this.

Comment: It is indeed a public service in a literal sense, but it's usually not taxonomically included as such because we call that _national service_, or even just _the service_, so the term _public service_ typically refers to explicitly non-military service.